# What is this condition testing?

Tags: python

in the following program:

```
count = 0
while True:
    count += 1
    if count>10:
         break
    if count==5:
        continue
    print(count)
```

what exactly is `while True` testing? And can there ever be a `while false` condition, if so what would that be testing?

Comment: Not what you want, but... on Python 2.x you could set `True` or `False` to anything... Apart from that it is a infinite loop until something breaks it

Comment: Yes, you can have `while False`. It wouldn't never execute the loop body, so it's not really useful.

Comment: The 'while true' construct is extremely important in programming. Think of any big program or video game you have ever used. If a program runs for more than a fraction of a second, it probably uses a loop like this. e.g. 'while true: accept user input, move character's position, redraw screen'

Answer (score 2):

It is an infinite loop. It tests if `True` is.. true, which it always is.

It is the conditions *in* the loop that end it; the `break` statement breaks out of the infinite loop here, not the `while` condition.

Note that the `continue` statement merely skips the remainder of the loop iteration and skips to the next.

Other events that'd end the loop are a `return` (provided the loop is part of a function), or an if an exception was raised.

Comment: Unless someone did `True = 0` first

Comment: @JBernardo which is thankfully forbidden in Python3 :) "SyntaxError: assignment to keyword"

Comment: so would `while False` always evaluate to true or false?

Comment: @user3131132: `False` is false. It's very easy to remember because it's the exact same word. Have a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: @user3131132: `while False:` would never loop because `False` is never true.

Answer (score 2):

`while True:` is an infinite loop. It will only ever be broken by `break`, `return`, or an exception being raised (in your case the first).

Comment: Unless someone did `True = 0` first

Comment: Or `print = sys.exit`.

Answer (score 0):

This will create an infinite loop, most likely causing your program to crash. If you would like to stop the loop, use `return`. You're code is pretty much counting up to 10, then stopping, as seen in

```
if count>10:
     break
```

a better way of doing this would be to use a for loop

```
for count in range(0, 10):
```

Comment: Why would this cause a program to crash?

Comment: @Wooble not in the code that he's using, but an infinite loop will cause a program to crash if there is no stop within it

Comment: That's a ridiculous assertion. Infinite loops don't cause crashes unless you're using a language with a horribly buggy interpreter or compiler.